# Calling another prototype function within a class prototype

Tags: javascript

I have a class prototype called "viewport", goes like this (its really long so just snippets)

```
function Viewport(Container) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.w = 0;
    this.h = 0; 
...
```

Then at some point I have this

```
    this.Draw = function() {
        this.Canvas.width = this.w;
        this.Canvas.height = this.h;
        cDrawGrid(this.ctx, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h, this.scale);
        //add other draw calls later
    }
```

And even further down the line I got this

```
    this.onMouseMove = function(e) {
        if (!this.bMoving) return;
        e = getEvent(e);
        this.x += e.clientX - this.LastMouseX;
        this.y += e.clientY - this.LastMouseY;
        this.LastMouseX = e.clientX;
        this.LastMouseY = e.clientY;
        this.Draw();
    }
```

It doesn't work however, opera error console says "Type error: this.Draw() is not a function"

Why is this happening?

Comment: And what is it? (use `console.log(typeof this.Draw)`). BTW, you miss semicolon after curly bracket ending Draw function.

Comment: Heh, so it looks like Opera is contradicting itself... Have you tried to add missing semicolon (also to `onMouseMove` and I presume other functions)?

Comment: yes i did just now (wasn't aware they needed it) but no change

Comment: I assume you've bound that method as an event handler, which means `this` is the element to which the handler is bound.

Comment: @Cromax: No Opera is not contradicting itself. The OP is doing something else wrong; he probably has the `console.log(this.Draw);` in the wrong place. And a "missing" semicolon isn't going to make any difference here.

Comment: yes "addEventHandler(this.Container, "mousemove", this.onMouseMove);". addEventHandler is a function that tried various methods for various browsers. Also tried chrome error console which says that the type is function and "undefined type is not a function"

Comment: As I said above, `this` is going to be a reference to the Element that has the handler bound.

Comment: oh i misunderstood, no. this has a reference to the element to which the handler is bound but in itself is a custom class prototype.

Comment: @cookiemonster Well, looks like you guessed. By "further down the line" I assumed it is still the part of `Viewport`.

Comment: @KarliRaudsepp: You've detached the method from the object that you want, and so the event handler caller sets it to the element. In your call to `addEventHandler`, you can do `this.onMouseMove.bind(this);`, though you'll need to patch it if you support old browsers.

Comment: @KarliRaudsepp check for the closures in JS. `this` can point to different objects depending on calling context. Cookiemonster's right.

Comment: so if I'm getting this right, instead of resolving this.method when the event listener is added, it tries to resolve it when the event is triggered?

Comment: You might want to learn what the value of `this` is and how to set it for event handlers. If you create multiple instances of Viewport or would like to inherit from it with an easy way to extend it's functions you can use prototype. That and the value of `this` is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: @KarliRaudsepp: Correct. That's how it works for functions in JavaScript. The value of `this` is almost always determined by the caller of the function *(by how it's called)*, not the creator or how it's created. The caller of the event handler is the event system, which sets `this` to reference the element.